# Django: Admin template shows old values after page refresh

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using Python 3.4 with Django 1.7 and PyCharm

I'm trying to extend django admin view by overriding AdminSite class

My  custom_admin.py:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # Text to put at the end of each page's <title>.
    site_title = ugettext_lazy('Test panel title')
    # My custom variable 
    import datetime
    srv_time = "%s" % datetime.datetime.now()


    def each_context(self):
        """
        Overriden dictionary of variables returned for
        *every* page in the admin site.
        """
        return {
            'site_title': self.site_title,
            'site_header': self.site_header,
            'srv_time': self.srv_time,
        }
```

Now i should be able to use my 'srv_time' variable in templates/admin/base.html:

```
Current date: {{ srv_time }}
```

And it works. Well kinda.
It displays current date correctly but when i refresh my webpage it doesn't update itself. It keeps showing old time.

Nothing helps except restarting debug webserver - then it shows current date again, but after page refresh it won't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `srv_time` is being set as a 'class' level attribute and not an 'instance' level attribute.

Python keeps two namespaces for both 'class' level attributes and 'instance' level attributes.

When Django gets loaded (when you start your server), it runs the calculation for `srv_time` just once.  This is why when you refresh the page it isn't recalculating this value.

You'll need to override the `__init__` function of `MyAdminSite` to have this calculation always run whenever the class gets instantiated as an object.

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # Text to put at the end of each page's <title>.
    site_title = ugettext_lazy('Test panel title')
    # My custom variable 
    import datetime
    srv_time = "%s" % datetime.datetime.now()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAdminSite, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.srv_time = "%s" % datetime.datetime.now()

    def each_context(self):
        """
        Overriden dictionary of variables returned for
        *every* page in the admin site.
        """
        return {
            'site_title': self.site_title,
            'site_header': self.site_header,
            'srv_time': self.srv_time,
        }
```

Alternatively, you could just do the calculation in the `each_context` function.

```
def each_context(self):
        """
        Overriden dictionary of variables returned for
        *every* page in the admin site.
        """
        return {
            'site_title': self.site_title,
            'site_header': self.site_header,
            'srv_time': "%s" % datetime.datetime.now(),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, your first method didn't worked but the second one works :)

Comment: Interesting... I wonder why?  I didn't test the first method I just assumed it would work :/.  Glad the second one worked!